# how to bind members of one object to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, binding

Here is my problem.  I have a class game, and i would like to bind some of the members to the datagrid, not entire object. What is better way to do it? Create another object to hold infomation, or create a datatable?

```
    public class Game
    {
        public string Name {get;set; }
        public string Description {get;set;}
        public string FullPath {get;set;}

    }

    List<Game> Games = new Games { game1, game2, game3 };

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Game;  // I don't want to do this it will bind entire object.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still bind the whole object, turn off automatic generation of columns and create and bind columns manually.

Comment: Wonder if you can have an exaple, or link to an example, that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create another class that inherits the game class. Game2 for example. Then create the constructor to only set what you want/need from game one. Using linq you can filter this out.

```
var newData = from item in game
              select new game 2
              {
                  object1 = item.object1,
                  object2 = item.object2
              };
```

Then you can set newData as the datasource. Forgive me for any syntax errors. If you look up linq this is a pretty easy concept. You don't need to even inherit the game class. You can create a independent class called game 2 with the info you need.

Comment: but it sound likes if i need to add/delete/update the information, i need to update them in both place.